# Join the two list into a tuple of 2 elements

Tags: python

I have the following arrays:

```
info = ['test', 'apple', 'cars', 'dog']
data = ['cat', 'list', 'text','code']
```

and I want to get the following result.

```
test   cat
apple  list
cars   text
dog    code
```

I did this with the following code:

```
for x, y in zip(info, data):
    print('{0:18} {1:}'.format(x,y))
```

it works, but maybe there are better options/way than mine?

Comment: That's not an intersection.

Comment: what you did if fine. It's not intersection though

Comment: What is it that you don't like about your solution? If you are using Python 3.6+ you can be slightly more concise with `print(f'{x:18} {y}')` but that's more of a stylistic choice than anything else...

Comment: As the others said you are not doing an intersection, `zip(info, data)` joins the two list into a tuple of 2 elements and then does a transposition.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x,y in zip(info,data):
     print("%s%s%s"%(x," "*(18-len(x)),y))
```

This looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of packages to print content in tabular form. I suggest to go up with `tabulate`

```
from tabulate import tabulate
t = tabulate(zip(info, data), tablefmt="plain")
print(t)
```

**Output**

```
test   cat
apple  list
cars   text
dog    code
```